# How to disable sendNotificationEmails using create method?

Tags: php, permissions, google-drive-api, email-notifications

I am using PHP Google drive API V2 and I want to stop sending notification emails while give permission using the **create** method. Below is my code:

```
foreach($EMAILS as $cnt=>$email){
    $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'role' => 'writer',            
    'emailAddress' => $email
    ));
    $request = $driveService->permissions->create(
        $fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
    $batch->add($request, 'user');
    $results[] = $batch->execute();                     
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this documentation for V2 I couldn't find the `create` method for permissions:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Permissions_Resource.html

In V3, it exists:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Permissions_Resource.html

For `$optParams` parameter, you have this:

> **Opt_param**
>
> **string emailMessage** A plain text custom message to include in the notification email.
>
> **bool sendNotificationEmail** Whether to send a notification email when sharing to users or groups. This defaults to true for users and
> groups, and is not allowed for other requests. It must not be disabled
> for ownership transfers.
>
> **bool supportsTeamDrives** Whether the requesting application supports Team Drives.
>
> **bool transferOwnership** Whether to transfer ownership to the specified user and downgrade the current owner to a writer. This
> parameter is required as an acknowledgement of the side effect.
>
> **bool useDomainAdminAccess** Whether the request should be treated as if it was issued by a domain administrator; if set to true, then the
> requester will be granted access if they are an administrator of the
> domain to which the item belongs.

You just need to send the **sendNotificationEmail** as false in that parameters array.

`'sendNotificationEmail'=>false`

Comment: Hello, It showing me the error as below:
 google-api-php-client.ERROR: Service parameter unknown {"service":"drive","resource":"permissions","method":"create","parameter":"sendNotificationEmails"} []
Error:(create) unknown parameter: 'sendNotificationEmails'

Comment: probably you need `sendNotificationEmail`? reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create